# __package__ is None when importing a Python module

Tags: python, module, load, dynamic

I want to import the modules dynamically, by the following way:

I create a folder named pkg with this structure:

```
pkg
   |__init__.py
   |foo.py
```

In the head of `__init__.py`, add this code fragement:

```
pkgpath = os.path.dirname(pkg.__file__);
for module in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkgpath]):
     __import__(module[1], locals(), globals());
     m = sys.modules[module[1]];
     print m.__package__;
```

I found `m.__package__` is `None` in case there is no import statements in foo.py
but if I add a simple import statement like this:

```
import os
```

then `m.__package__` is "pkg" which is correct package name.
why this happens?

How to import a module and ensure its correct package attribute?

Comment: It is hard to see your goal. At least show how do you intend to call or import pkg.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Let me give my goal: I need create a function to load all modules a package which is provided in run-time. The package can be nested-which means there is sub package in this package. In case all modules are correctly loaded, another function will analyze the relationship between any two modules. For example, if the __package__ attribute in one module is name of another module, then the latter is the package of the former.

Answer (score 11):

The `__package__` attribute, as you've noticed, isn't set consistently. (More information at the bottom.)  However, you should always be able to get the package name by taking everything before the last period in a module's `__name__` attribute.  Eg. `mymod.__name__.rpartition('.')[0]`.  For your purpose though, it's probably easier just to build the package/module hierarchy as you load the modules.

For example, here's a function that loads all the modules within a package, recursively loading modules within subpackages, etc.  (I'm assuming here that you don't mind functions with side-effects..)

```
import sys
import pkgutil
from os.path import dirname

def loadModules(pkg):
    pkg._modules = []

    pkgname = pkg.__name__
    pkgpath = dirname(pkg.__file__)

    for m in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkgpath]):
        modulename = pkgname+'.'+m[1]
        __import__(modulename, locals(), globals())
        module = sys.modules[modulename]

        module._package = pkg
        # module._packageName = pkgname

        pkg._modules.append(module)
        if dirname(module.__file__) == pkgpath:
            module._isPackage = False
        else:
            module._isPackage = True
            loadModules(module)


def modName(mod):
    return mod.__name__.rpartition('.')[-1]

def printModules(pkg, indent=0):
    print '\t'*indent, modName(pkg), ':'
    indent += 1
    for m in pkg._modules:
        if m._isPackage:
            printModules(m, indent)
        else:
            print '\t'*indent, modName(m)

import dummypackage
loadModules(dummypackage)
printModules(dummypackage)
```

Sample output:

```
dummypackage :
    modx
    mody
    pack1 :
        mod1
        pack2 :
            mod2
```

More information:

The `__package__` attribute is used internally by the import system to allow for easy relative imports within a package.  For details, see [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/).  To (presumably) save time when loading modules, the attribute is only set if the loaded module imports another module.