# Execution of Python code with -m option or not

Tags: python, module, package

The python interpreter has `-m` *module* option that "Runs library module *module* as a script".

With this python code a.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print __package__
    print __name__
```

I tested `python -m a` to get

```
"" <-- Empty String
__main__
```

whereas `python a.py` returns

```
None <-- None
__main__
```

To me, those two invocation seems to be the same except __package__ is not None when invoked with -m option.

Interestingly, with `python -m runpy a`, I get the same as `python -m a` with python module compiled to get a.pyc.

What's the (practical) difference between these invocations? Any pros and cons between them?

Also, David Beazley's Python Essential Reference explains it as "*The -m option runs a library module as a script which executes inside the __main__ module prior to the execution of the main script*". What does it mean?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

When you use the [`-m` command-line flag](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), Python will import a module *or package* for you, then run it as a script. When you don't use the `-m` flag, the file you named is run as *just a script*.

The distinction is important when you try to run a package. There is a big difference between:

```
python foo/bar/baz.py
```

and

```
python -m foo.bar.baz
```

as in the latter case, `foo.bar` is imported and relative imports will work correctly with `foo.bar` as the starting point.

Demo:

```
$ mkdir -p test/foo/bar
$ touch test/foo/__init__.py
$ touch test/foo/bar/__init__.py
$ cat << EOF > test/foo/bar/baz.py 
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     print __package__
>     print __name__
> 
> EOF
$ PYTHONPATH=test python test/foo/bar/baz.py 
None
__main__
$ PYTHONPATH=test python -m foo.bar.baz 
foo.bar
__main__
```

As a result, Python has to actually care about packages when using the `-m` switch. A normal script can never *be* a package, so `__package__` is set to `None`.

But run a package or module *inside* a package with `-m` and now there is at least the *possibility* of a package, so the `__package__` variable is set to a string value; in the above demonstration it is set to `'foo.bar'`, for plain modules not inside a package it is set to an empty string.

As for the `__main__` *module*, Python imports scripts being run as it would import regular modules. A new module object is created to hold the global namespace and is stored in `sys.modules['__main__']`. This is what the `__name__` variable refers to, it is a key in that structure.

For packages, you can create a `__main__.py` module inside and have that run when running `python -m package_name`; in fact that is the only way you *can* run a package as a script:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=test python -m foo.bar
python: No module named foo.bar.__main__; 'foo.bar' is a package and cannot be directly executed
$ cp test/foo/bar/baz.py test/foo/bar/__main__.py
$ PYTHONPATH=test python -m foo.bar
foo.bar
__main__
```

So, when naming a package for running with `-m`, Python looks for a `__main__` module contained in that package and executes that as a script. Its name is then still set to `'__main__'` and the module object is still stored in `sys.modules['__main__']`.

Comment: When a module inside a package that does not import other modules also has __package__ == None: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437394/package-is-none-when-importing-a-python-module

Comment: What actually does command `PYTHONPATH=test python -m foo.bar` mean? Could you explain it in details, please?

Comment: @Andriy: `PYTHONPATH` sets an environment variable; it expands the series of directories where Python will look for modules when importing; here it adds the `test` directory to that series. By putting it on the same command line, it applies *only* to that single `python` command. `-m` tells Python to import a specific module, as if you ran `import foo.bar`. However, Python will automatically run a `__main__` module inside a package as a script when you use that switch.

Comment: Now that we can use `-m` for a single module or a module in package, why don't we only use `-m` for running python modules. Why there is entrance like Django `manage.py`?

Comment: @SiminJie because `-m` requires that the target module is findable on the module search path, which limits your options  (you can’t use an ad hoc file in a random subdirectory somewhere, while a script file would work just fine). `manage.py` Is a different case, as it can be custom generated for each Django project. Besides, having to use `-m` **always** is not that user-.friendly.

Comment: `having to use -m always is not that user-.friendly.` I think mix using and not using `-m` is lesser user friendly.

Comment: `-m requires that the target module is findable on the module search path`. Current working directory will always in search path.

Comment: @SiminJie: scripts can be opened in *any arbitrary path* and then their parent directory is added to the module search path. `-m` only works for the current directory or directories already registered on the search path. That was my point. `-m` is not something you give to end-users for that very usability issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To clarify, the absolute path of `foo` is `/home/flow2k/foo`, which is the Python project root. There are other files and directories, like `/home/flowk/Java/` and `/home/flow2k/Photos`. So to execute `python -m foo.bar.baz`, I have to `cd /home/flow2k/` first; this command puts `/home/flow2k/` on `sys.path`, which is undesirable. Would you have a solution for this?

Comment: @flow2k: My question is: *why is it undesirable*? Only Python modules and packages will be loaded, other subdirectories don't matter.  You can otherwise introduce an extra directory (e.g. `/home/flow2k/python`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters About it being undesirable, I guess I want to have some kind "controlled environment" or "isolation" when I run my Python scripts. Had I written `import Photos` (a pointless statement that's probably a bug), the interpreter would not complain because the Photos directory exists, but if I deleted the Photos directory someday while cleaning up my home directory, my program would immediately fail. This kind of dependence on external factors is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Yes, introducing the extra directory, i.e. making `/home/flow2k/python/foo`, would solve the problem for me.

Comment: @flow2k If this is Python 3.3 or newer it would only complain if you used a plain `import Photos` with no use of the module, as it is treated as an [implicit namespace package](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages); in older Python versions that would still be an import error.  And code quality issues like unused imports can trivially be caught by running a linter like `flake8` on your code, you should do so for any published project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters About your first point " it would only complain if you used a plain import Photos with no use of the module" - I tried `import Photos` with no subsequent use of `Photos`, and it did not complain. Did I misunderstand you? Thanks for pointing to `flake8` by the way.

Comment: @flow2k: I mean that `from Photos import ...` will complain. So would `import Photos.<something>`. `import Photos` only works because Python supports namespaced packages (where two separate distributions provide `Photos.foo` and `Photos.bar` separately and they can independently be managed).

Comment: "When you use the `-m` command-line flag, Python will import a module or package for you, then run it as a script. When you don't use the `-m` flag, the file you named is run as just a script." Two questions: 1. What do you mean by *import*? I thought it meant running a module’s code in the current environment. 2. What do you mean by *run as a script*? I am wondering if a module can *not* be run as a script.

Comment: @Maggyero: all scripts are modules, but they are imported as the `__main__` module. They loose their package context, however. Importing is a two-step process: loading if the name doesn't yet exist in `sys.modules`, and binding (assigning to a name), so `import foo.bar as spam` finds *something* to be stored in `sys.modules['foo.bar']`, and then binds the name `spam`. For scripts and `-m` there is no visible binding, however, but the module needs loading in the first place.

Comment: @Maggyero: Any `.py` file can be run as a script as well as being imported. What differs (between running as a script and using `-m`) is the *context*, how `sys.path` is affected and if the loaded module is part of a package, whether or not the package is also imported and so have a module that can use package-relative imports.

Comment: "`import foo.bar as spam` finds *something* to be stored in `sys.modules['foo.bar']`" Does it only *find* the module, or does it also *execute* its code before storage in `sys.modules['foo.bar']` (in other words, load = find + execute + store)?

Comment: @Maggyero: sorry, comments are not really suitable for a full expose of how the Python import system works. In short, if `sys.modules` doesn't have it, then yes, something needs to be loaded. Usually that's finding a module file and executing it.

Answer (score 55):

## Execution of Python code with -m option or not

Use the `-m` flag.

The results are pretty much the same when you have a script, but when you develop a package, without the `-m` flag, there's no way to get the imports to work correctly if you want to run a subpackage or module in the package as the main entry point to your program (and believe me, I've tried.)

### The docs

Like the [docs on the -m flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) say:

> Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.

and

> As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

so

```
python -m pdb
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
python /usr/lib/python3.5/pdb.py
```

(assuming you don't have a package or script in your current directory called pdb.py)

### Explanation:

Behavior is made "deliberately similar to" scripts.

> Many standard library modules contain code that is invoked on their execution as a script. An example is the [timeit module:](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Some python code is intended to be [run as a module:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) (I think this example is better than the commandline option doc example)

```
$ python -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.3 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])'
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.4 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.2 usec per loop
```

[And from the release note highlights for Python 2.4](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4/highlights/):

> The -m command line option - python -m modulename will find a module
>   in the standard library, and invoke it. For example, `python -m pdb`
>   is equivalent to `python /usr/lib/python2.4/pdb.py`

### Follow-up Question

> Also, David Beazley's Python Essential Reference explains it as "The
>   -m option runs a library module as a script which executes inside the `__main__` module prior to the execution of the main script".

It means any module you can lookup with an import statement can be run as the entry point of the program - if it has a code block, usually near the end, with `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

### `-m` without adding the current directory to the path:

A comment here elsewhere says:

> That the -m option also adds the current directory to sys.path, is obviously a security issue (see: preload attack). This behavior is similar to library search order in Windows (before it had been hardened recently). It's a pity that Python does not follow the trend and does not offer a simple way to disable adding . to sys.path

Well, this demonstrates the possible issue - (in windows remove the quotes):

```
echo "import sys; print(sys.version)" > pdb.py

python -m pdb
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Use the `-I` flag to lock this down for production environments (new in version 3.4):

```
python -Im pdb
usage: pdb.py [-c command] ... pyfile [arg] ...
etc...
```

from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-I):

> **`-I`**
>
> Run Python in isolated mode. This also implies -E and -s. In isolated mode sys.path contains neither the script’s directory nor the user’s site-packages directory. All PYTHON* environment variables are ignored, too. Further restrictions may be imposed to prevent the user from injecting malicious code.

#### What does `__package__` do?

It enables explicit relative imports, not particularly germane to this question, though - see this answer here: [What's the purpose of the "__package__" attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python/48833828#48833828)

Comment: Which path is added to the sys.path when the -m switch is used?

Comment: I already have that quoted, "As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path." but I have clarified what the quote refers to.

Comment: I mean that - suppose in D:\test directory, I run the command - python -m foo.bar.boo then will this add the python installation folder or the D:\test directory to sys.path? My understanding is that it will add d:\test to sys.path, import foo.bar and run boo script

Comment: @variable - yes, try it.

Answer (score 8):

The main reason to run a module (or package) as a script with -m is to simplify deployment, especially on Windows. You can install scripts in the same place in the Python library where modules normally go - instead of polluting PATH or global executable directories such as ~/.local (the per-user scripts directory is ridiculously hard to find in Windows).

Then you just type -m and Python finds the script automagically. For example, `python -m pip` will find the correct pip for the same instance of Python interpreter which executes it. Without -m, if user has several Python versions installed, which one would be the "global" pip?

If user prefers "classic" entry points for command-line scripts, these can be easily added as small scripts somewhere in PATH, or pip can create these at install time with entry_points parameter in setup.py.

So just check for `__name__ == '__main__'` and ignore other non-reliable implementation details.

Comment: That the -m option also adds the current directory to sys.path, is obviously a security issue (see: **preload attack**). This behavior is similar to library search order in Windows (before it had been hardened recently). It's a pity that Python does not follow the trend and does not offer a simple way to disable adding . to sys.path.

Comment: ddbug: In Python 3.4+ there is `-I` flag to run the script in isolated mode, which will not add current directory to sys.path.