# Difference between pip3 and python3 -m pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install some packages using pip and python3. I am using MacOS, so by default when I run pip, it uses my version of Python 2.

I have been able to install a package in python 3 by using:

```
$ pip3 install package_name
```

However, I am able to do the same by (at least it seems):

```
$ python3 -m pip install package_name
```

I wonder whether or not `pip3` and `python3 -m pip` have the same effect.

Comment: Not specific to Python, but...  Your shell could behave differently, because it's looking up two different names.  Sometimes, new software is installed out under `/usr/local/` or weirder places, and the only concession to the typical `$PATH` or filesystem hierarchy is a hand-crafted symlink like `/usr/bin/python3 -> /opt/experimental/python3.2-local-myedit/bin/python`.  Often in these setups, only the "star" binary like `python` or `perl` gets symlinked, while everything else from related binaries (like `pip`) to manual pages send users to whatever came on the OS's installation media.

Comment: Personal scripts, shell functions, and aliases are subject to similar errors.   Example:  Sourcing some config file before running `python`, but not `pip`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They are the same. If you look at the pip3 file in the bin folder it calls the `main` function from the pip module.

`pip3 install package_name` runs pip3 file in the bin folder:

```
# bin/pip3 
# or bin/pip if using pip install package_name

import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

`python3 -m pip install package_name` runs the `__init__.py` file of the [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/__init__.py) module.

```
# pip/__init__.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Both of them run the same `main()` function

Comment: thank you, I know how to see the code of `pip3` (`$ less /usr/local/bin/pip3`), but how did you know the code that `python3 -m pip install ....` uses?

Comment: as Kevin J. Chase suggests, it is possible that the shell is looking up two different names. Is there any way to ensure what you are stating? I mean how to know the code that is executed with `$ python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: `python3 -m module` would run the the `__init__.py` file of the module. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not) for more detailed explanation

Comment: barring some weird setup. The path for both `pip3` and `python3` should be the same `bin` folder. In that case they would call the same `pip` module.

Comment: @tihorn thanks for the tip, I just got bitten by one of those "weird setups". The path for pip3 was `/usr/bin/pip3` and the path for python3 was `~/anaconda3/bin/python3`. I was installing packages with pip3 and then python3 was telling me `ModuleNotFound`.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are technically correct, but are a little unclear on **why** Python has both `pip3` and `python3 -m pip`:

Using `pip3` to globally install a package can be *ambiguous* if you have multiple Python installations on your machine.

Many people end up with multiple Python installations after they upgrade their computer's operating system. OS upgrades usually install a new Python, but they do not risk purging the old Python and breaking existing programs on the computer.

For these reasons, on my own computer, I always install with the specific version, e.g: `python3.8 -m pip`. When I am writing Makefiles or build scripts to distribute to others, I default to `python3 -m pip` but let the user optionally replace `python3` with their own interpreter path.

Answer (score 8):

As @tihorn says, `pip3` and `python3 -m pip` *should* be the same. There is at least one exception: if they are not in the same path. I had the following setup:

```sh
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
$ which python3
/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

After installing modules with pip3 and verifying with `pip3 freeze`, I was not able to access them when running `python3 my_script.py` or `python3 -c 'import my_module'`. I was getting a `ModuleNotFound` error.