# Python/BeautifulSoup Download

Tags: python, download, beautifulsoup, error-messages-for

I have `Python 3.0.1` and `beautifulsoup 4.1.0` but when I try and run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I have read that some of the versions of beautiful soup don't work with certain versions of Python but because I am unfamiliar and haven't used either before I am unsure of which versions I should download.

Comment: Just open python terminal and type `pip install bs4`.. It should work fine with Python 3.x. also you can take a look at the [Installation Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup), and at your `path environment variables` too...

Comment: How did you install it? With `pip` or `pip3`? If the former, please try the latter.

Comment: @ForceBru aren't they [the same method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307101/difference-between-pip3-and-python3-m-pip)?

Comment: @dot.Py, no, they generally aren't, and your link is about the difference between `pip3` the standalone command and `pip` the Python 3.x module, which are, indeed, the same, but not about the differences between `pip` & `pip3`.