# ImportError cannot import 'langauge' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, importerror, google-cloud-language

I'm trying to incorporate google-cloud-language to use sentiment analysis. I followed the guide on the google documentation website, like so:

```
from google.cloud import language
```

When I run the script I receive the following error:

```
ImportError cannot import 'langauge' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I try to run the script like so:

```
python3 scriptName.py
```

I've installed google-cloud-language like so:

```
pip3 install gooogle-cloud-language

pip install google-cloud-language
```

I've done that in a virtual environment and outside a virtual environment.

Nothing works. How do I properly set up my script to successfully import the NLP module from google cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to see that you resolved your issue. However, I would like to point some things out:

1. In the error that you posted in the description there is a typo. It looked for a module named `langauge` instead of `language`.
2. `pip3 install gooogle-cloud-language` and `python3 -m pip install google-cloud-language` should be equivalent but that may not always be the case. For example when they are not in the same path. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57155119/7903159) for more details.

Comment: I noticed this typo in the word language as well. It caused a secondary error, but I guess it's likely to have caused this error too. I now can't remember if I fixed the typo before trying the python3 -m pip install command. Well, either way. Nice to have an answer and it working. Hopefully this post will help other people, typo or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this question and going through other similar questions on stackoverflow, I found another command to try and it seems to have worked.

```
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-language
```

I did this inside my virtualenv. It could also work outside of one, but because I got it working, I did not test the outside virtualenv case.

Comment: Please mark your answer (or mine) as the accepted one so this question can appear as answered. Thanks!