# Why unit tests in Python need -m option?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm reading Python's documentation about unit tests and just noticed the `-m` flag when [running test cases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface):

There are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not) about the purpose of the `-m` flag, so I know it runs modules as scripts and also there's a [full explanation here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) about why it is needed.

My question is specific to unit tests: why do they need to run as scripts?

The documentation just throws `-m` in all examples, but I could not find the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *still* running a module. The command is:

```
python -m unittest <path_to_your_script>
```

`unittest` *is* the module and you are passing positional arguments to *unittest*.

If you actually run the help against unittest:

```
python -m unittest --help
```

You will get a long output explaining how to use it. Namely, this particular piece that explains exactly how to use it:

```
  python -m unittest test_module               - run tests from test_module
  python -m unittest module.TestClass          - run tests from module.TestClass
  python -m unittest module.Class.test_method  - run specified test method
```

Even explained in the help, is a statement about the *positional* arguments that are passed:

```
positional arguments:
  tests           a list of any number of test modules, classes and test
                  methods.
```