# Difference between running python file as a module executed as a script vs just running python?

Tags: python

What's the difference between running python file as a module executed as a script vs just running the python file? In particular, I'm wondering what the difference is between running

`python -m filename` vs
`python filename.py`

I'm reading the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html but it's not entirely clear to me.

In particular, I notice that when I'm running a file I wrote that imports other modules I've written, it works when I run `python -m filename` but when I run `python filename.py` it says it can't find the module I've written. Why is this? Is this something to do with the path?

Comment: Please include a minimal example of a file that runs one way, but not the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a python guy but I read something in the link you have provided that may provide some explanation.

> If this option is given, the first element of sys.argv will be the
>   full path to the module file (while the module file is being located,
>   the first element will be set to "-m"). As with the -c option, the
>   current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

I guess what that means is that the directory you are running `python -m filename` is added to the system path. The `sys.path` (or system path) is basically a list of paths (folders) that python will try search for the file you are trying to import. I am assuming the files you are looking for in your import is in the same folder you run `python -m filename`. Running python without the -m does not modify the sys.path list.

You can read more on this here https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.path

Hope this is what you want.