# what does "-m" do in this command "python -m pip install beautifulsoup"

Tags: python, command-prompt

I was typing the commands to install Beautiful Soup. I never knew what `-m` does in the command, so I got curious but I couldn't find much results online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not

Comment: Those are called options, which can be seen on the command's `man` page. So Python's man page is https://linux.die.net/man/1/python . And according to that, it's to denote module name