# What word is the -m switch a shortcut for in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

When creating a virtual environment, I run:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

I understand that `-m` [executes a module](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) (`venv` in this case). I also know that it only works if you have a `__main__.py` file in your module. So, what does the shortcut `-m` actually stand for?

Is it:

1. `-m` for **module** or
2. `-m` for **`__main__`**
3. Something else?

I couldn't find an unambiguous explanation. Here are some resources I investigated:

- https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0547/
- [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not)

Comment: I always liked to think of it as `-m` for **make**, but I know that's incorrect ; )

Comment: -m is for module

Comment: Do you have any resources that state this clearly @VineethSai? If so, please post it and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: in section 1.1.1 It clearly says -m is module name https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Comment: It doesn't stand for anything.

Comment: Please add some notes on why this question was downvoted so that I can improve. I felt it was a valid question to ask on SO and I did my research. Thanks!

Comment: @martin-martin, I'm on board with the downvote (but would be even more on-board with an off-topic close vote) because knowing the answer doesn't change how one goes about the _practice_ of programming, and Stack Overflow's scope is explicitly limited to _practical_ questions. The recent edit makes the curiosity-based, impractical nature even more clear.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay thank you for clarifying. Would you suggest to delete the question, or keep it in its current state where it's marked as a duplicate? Or should we change the status to "Off topic"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in 
 section 1.1.1
 It clearly says `-m` is the module name, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html).

Quoting from the docs :

*"since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file extension (.py). The module-name should be a valid Python module name"*

Although `-m` is arbitrary as in the backend It is an argparser doing all the work.

When called with -m module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script

*Package names are also permitted. When a package name is supplied instead of a normal module, the interpreter will execute `<pkg>.__main__`*  And I guess the `main` also starting with 'm' is a coincidence.

Comment: Hei, I don't think that the docs you linked clearly explain that this is what `-m` stands for. I am still okay accepting your answer, but could you improve it by linking this sentence instead: `When called with -m module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.` and using a more up-to-date Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html

Comment: Updated it. Thanks

Comment: When python -m pkg runs, and if the pkg has got a __main__ file then it will also run. But what about the __init__ file?

Answer (score 1):

It runs the module following `-m`. See [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options)

The documentation says `-m <module-name>`, as well as "Since the argument is a module name...", so it makes sense to assume that "m" stands for module.

Comment: The question is "What does the `m` stand for", not "What does the `-m` flag do".