# How to run a Python package with one command line

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python. And I don't know how to run a python package with only one command line. I have been searched it on GG but I have no key-word. 
There is my folder:

```
├── config.json
└── my_source
    ├──__init__.py
    ├──filter.py
    └──get_new_users.py
```

And config.json contains 3 parameters and able change by the user. So, I want to run this my_source package with one command line like this:

> my_source -c config.json

Could I able to run my code in this way? 
If it's possible. Could anyone give me a key-word or a way to do it? If you need more info, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Comment: you mean execute the script?

Comment: you are right. @KunalMukherjee

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> **To run a python module/package specify the [-m flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).**

For example in your situation it will be something like:

```
python -m my_course.filter
```

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not) for more info.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for how the OPs question is phrased. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean "run a folder". Rather you can import the folder as a module, in other code, say `app.py`

```
├── config.json
├── app.py
└── my_source
    ├──__init__.py
    ├──filter.py
    └──get_new_users.py
```

And do `from my_source import *` within `app.py` to use the function/variables defined there

Then, run `python app.py`, and pass `config.json` somehow depending on the internals of that code

Comment: Thank you. 
In case if I want to make it as a package. How can I run it?

Comment: Perhaps you can check some documentation about packages? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages