# Structuring python module so it can be run from a command line with and without -m switch

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, module, python-import

## Background

I'm working on Python module that consists of a number of of scripts. The end goal is to make functions in this module importable via `import` statement when working interactively and to make certain parts of module executable via command line arguments.

## Desired outcome

Module can be run using:

```
python -m ./my_module --help
# No -m switch
python ./my_module --help
```

## Structure

Following on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22250157/1655567) I would like to understand relationship that **`-m`** switch has to `__main__.py` and `__init__.py` files. The current structure is a follows

### `__main__.py`

```
# Shebang line


###########
# Modules #
###########
import argparse
import logging
import tempfile


###################
# Package modules #
###################
from utilities import check_directory_access
# ...


#################
# Run functions #
#################
def run(args):
    """Run all functions with provided arguments"""
    # Start logging configuration
    # If file is not provided use temporary file
    if args.log_file is None:
        args.log_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,
                                                    prefix='my_module',
                                                    suffix='.log').name
    # Create handlers: console
    # logging configuration
    logging.shutdown()


def main():
    """Process arguments and run main function"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dop stuff module',
                                     epilog='Epilog')
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--tables", nargs='+', dest='tables',
                        help="List tables to refresh", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--log-file", dest='log_file',
                        type=str, help="Log file")
    parser.set_defaults(func=run)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### `__init__.py`

```
###################
# Package modules #
###################
from .utilities import check_directory_access
# Other components
```

## Problem

Running:

```
python -m my_module --help
```

Returns

> ImportError: No module named 'utilities'

whereas

```
python my_module --help
```

works with no problem

## Desired outcome

- Structring import in a manner that both statements `python my_module` and `python -m my_module` work.
- Not breaking `import my_module` when working interactively
- *(bonus)* Running without calling `python` interpreter first by `./my_module --help`. I'm not sure how to do it with tree:

  ```
  |-- my_module
  |   |-- my_module.py
  |   |-- __init__.py
  |   |-- __main__.py
  |   |-- module_component_A.py
  |   |-- utilities.py
  ```

  Is there specific content that should go to `my_module.py`?

Comment: What is the content of my_module.py?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Nothing at the moment; `my_module.py` would call `__main__.py`. IMHO, executing `./my_module/my_module.py` is prettier than `./my_module/__main__.py` but this is a side gadget. The key things are that the module is importable for interactive work and that it can be called from the command line to perform some basic operations. Also, I mostly program in R and I'm used to working with R package architecture; I want to understand Python's import/export mechanisms better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 does not have implied relative imports. Use absolute or explicit relative imports:

```
from .utilities import check_directory_access
from my_module.utilities import check_directory_access
```

This makes your package work with the `-m` switch. It also allows for `import my_module` in an interactive session.

---

A bare package stored as a folder cannot be executed directly. This is due to the operating system itself. You have to create an executable file that runs your package, if you wish to avoid calling python explicitly.

Either store the package as an executable zip file, or create a script that runs your package.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import my_module.__main__
```

Note that the later requires your module to be installed or directly adjacent to your script. If your module is viable for installation, a [`console_scripts` `entry_point`](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/#entry-points-specification) allows to have such a script created automatically.

You should not have the script reside inside your package - this requires you to change `sys.path` to a parent directory, which can lead to duplicate modules. For example, `utilities.py` would be available as the separate modules `my_module.utilities` *and* `utilities`.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question on your answer; what's a good practice for structuring import across **`__main__.py`** and **`__init__.py`**?

Comment: @Konrad ``__init__.py`` should not do any importing, unless you want to flatten some private namespace. ``__main__.py`` should only import the things it needs to execute.