# Docker image for Flask applicatno

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

when a run a simple flask application with a specified port(5888) from the console it is running well and is provided with a
URL:   * Debugger PIN: 125-876-281
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5888/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

for the same application when I build a docker image and run using the comman : **docker run  -p 192.168.0.152:5888:5888 dock_test** is is giving the
URL :  *** Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://172.17.0.3:5000**   with the different port(5000).

The main python file: **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "running"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True,port=5888)
```

docker file: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install Flask
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
ENV LISTEN_PORT=5888
EXPOSE 5888
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
WORKDIR C:\Users\heman\PycharmProjects\dock_test\main.py
COPY . .
ENV FLASK_APP=main.py
CMD ["python3","-m","flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

**Step-1:** To build the image I've run : **docker build -t dock_test .**(it created the docker     image well)

**step-2:** To run : **docker run  -d -p 5888:5888 dock_test**
**output:**  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://172.17.0.3:5000
**why the port is changing to 5000 instead of 5888?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the port number in the Dockerfile.

In your docker file, you are calling your application as a module (by using -m). When you run a module, it's first imported internally and then runs the function inside it. You can find more details here: [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not)

So basically, the if "____main___" part is skipped when you call using the -m command. Thus, the flask app is defaulting to the default port 5000. If you specify it in the Dockerfile, as shown below, it should work.

```
CMD ["python3","-m", "flask", "run","--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5888"]
```