# Getting unexpected sys.argv when running script as a module

Tags: python, sys

test.py:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Running normally:

`C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\python.exe ['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', 'test.py']`

Running as a module:

`C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\python.exe ['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\susha\\Documents\\Test\\test.py']`

Expectation:
`C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\python.exe ['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', '-m', 'test']`

How I am going to use it:

```
for path, _, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".py") and os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, file)) > self.init_time:
            print(file, os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, file)), os.path.getmtime(__file__))
            self.logger.info("File<%s> changed. Reloading..." % file)
            print(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
            os.execv(sys.executable, sys.argv)
```

Comment: There's no Python API exposing the original command line options used to run the script. What use case do you have for it?

Comment: Your concern seems odd, because in virtually every case the behavior that is provided is exactly what you want.

Comment: I am making a package that needs to restart on file change. I need it to restart using os.execv(). Also, it needs to be run exactly how it was started (My implementation needs to be run using `-m`). Do note that some implementations might not be run as a module. 

Any alternative way to restart?

Comment: @TimRoberts I need
**['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', '-m', 'test']**,
I get:
**['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\susha\\Documents\\Test\\test.py']**

Comment: This is exactly how `-m` is [documented to work](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). You wouldn't be able to rerun the exact command line your script was run with anyway, because Python doesn't provide access to that info. There are tons of other flags besides `-m`, and Python doesn't give you access to those either.

Comment: No, you DON'T need that.  The whole point of the `-m` flag is to SIMULATE running the module as a standalone script, and that's what `sys.argv` reflects.

Comment: If you just want to know if the script is run using the `-m` option, check the `__package__` variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not

Comment: @TimRoberts so does executing this command have the same effect as -m? Any edge cases where this doesn't work?

Comment: HAVE you read the documentation?  That's how it is defined.  https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

The original command line used to run a Python script is not exposed by the Python API, but can be obtained from a platform-dependent system call, which, conveniently, has been written as the [`Process.cmdline`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes) method in the cross-platform library [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/):

```
import psutil
print(psutil.Process().cmdline())
```

If you run the script above as `python -mtest`, it would output:

```
['/path/to/python', '-mtest']
```